# Symfony entity nulled ID

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm beginner in Symfony 3 and getting some serious problems.

First of all, let's see my entities classess.

Client.php <- Bundle/Entity/Client.php

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientBundle\Entity\Client\Address", mappedBy="cliEntity")
     */
    private $addresses;
}
```

Address.php <- Bundle/Entity/Client/Address.php

```
class Address
{
    /* same as Client one annotations */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * ID of client that address related to
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $client_id;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClientBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="addresses", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $cliEntity;
}
```

And in controller:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->set(...)

$em->persist($client);
$em->flush();

/* var_dump($client->getId()); <-- returns 40, 41, 42, etc. */

$addr = new Address();
$addr->setClient($client->getId()); /* There is null, why? */
```

Comment: What serious problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

`$addr->setClient($client);`

and finally this

`$em->flush();`

You don't need getId() for relation. You can use objects with doctrine ORM.

Comment: sorry about wrong info. I removed wrong parts. Did you update database structure ?

Comment: Yup, no effect. I've tried every combination of annotations, renaming variables, dumping. No idea for now.

Comment: May try $addr->setClient($em->getReference(\Path\To\Class ,$client->getId()); regards

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I found a solution:

I added this function in Address Entity:

```
    public function setCliEntity($cli)
    {
        $this->cliEntity = $cli;
        return $this;
    }
```

then in controller:

```
    //$address->setClient($client->getId());
    $address->setCliEntity($client);
```

Thanks for help anyway